# Inflate lzma zip file with java

Tags: java, zip, inflate, lzma

I have some zip files, their first bytes in hex editor are : 504B0304 (PK..)

I need to inflate them with java code, but even though they have zip file structure they are compressed with lzma, I know it because I inflated them with 7zip.

So I need to find a library to inflate zip files compressed with lzma, Do anyone knows one and any example of how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the zip filesystem provider?

Comment: Did you even _try_ google for this?  http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zip4jvm](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/zip4jvm) supports LZMA compression for zip archive.